# Git Hard Reset with fail

Tags: git

I get this error message when I try to rollback to one specific commit:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument ´2a92a39´: unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

The command I have used to it is

```
git reset --hard 2a92a39
```

**EDIT:**
With the full SHA-1 I got:

```
fatal: Could not parse object ´2a92a39a121383cdae92bfecb7f2e2120e0cdd5f´
```

*Github for Windows* doesn't have this option?

My git project is [here](https://github.com/uniritter-2015/controle-filmes-assistidos).

Comment: It means that your argument `2a99a39` is wrong.

Comment: How did you determine the SHA to use?  Post the commands you used and the output from them.

Comment: I get the SHA in the github for Windows on top of the selected commit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inspecting your repo it appears that you have a typo in your commit id which is `2a92a39`, i.e. a `2` after the first `9`

[image]

Regarding your edit, then did you verify that you got this commit on your local repo? Is it possible that you're on a branch not containing this commit? Is it possible that your repo got corrupted?

There are two things you can check:

1. Try cloning to a new local repo and rerun the command (just to make sure that you got the commit in the right branch and your repo is not corrupted
2. As this commit is 7 commits far from your HEAD you can try running `git reset --hard HEAD~7` (you might want to try running `git checkout HEAD~7` first, just to make sure that this will bring you to the right place)

Comment: How! It worked! I would never figured it out by myself. Thanks!

Comment: Just from curiosity - which of the options worked - #1 or #2?

Comment: Sorry... Number 1. Just cloned the repo then I run the hard --reset and created a new branch.

Answer (score 0):

In the command line, you copy the full  SHA-1 code and paste it into the terminal something like:

```
git reset --hard 597650788e74c5d34a45dac1cb5e318577b0ce2e
```

That way, it will reverse and go back where they were. Hope this helps!

Edit: Sometimes `git reset --hard` can be wacky at times but cloning will resolve this problem.

Comment: With the full SHA-1 I got: fatal: Could not parse object ´2a92a39a121383cdae92bfecb7f2e2120e0cdd5f´

Comment: Maybe that commit does not exist? Check your SHA-1 number for further rundown.

Comment: Don´t get it... The commit is [here](https://github.com/uniritter-2015/controle-filmes-assistidos/commit/2a92a39a121383cdae92bfecb7f2e2120e0cdd5f)

Comment: Oh, wait. ```2a92a39a121383cdae92bfecb7f2e2120e0cdd5f``` is a actual commit. How about ```git reset [SHA-1 commit here]```

Comment: Same thing `fatal: Could not parse object ´2a92a39a121383cdae92bfecb7f2e2120e0cdd5f´`

Comment: I will take a look at your problem right now. Will send a pull request when done.

Comment: Try cloning it again and perform the same operation again, it works perfectly on my Windows client.